# Xpath for specific elements

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rselenium

I have a problem to scrape specific element text from this webpage:

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/benin-togo-IsfnZDFd/

This is url for a specific match in archived results and I need to scrape odds from 4 bookmakers on this page. I have thousands of match url's which I want to scrape. The code looks like this:

This is what I tried to find the bookmaker odds but it does not work:

```
pjs <- wdman::phantomjs()

eCap <- list(phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent 
             = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 
  Firefox/29.0", phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages = FALSE, phantomjs.phantom.cookiesEnabled = TRUE, phantomjs.phantom.javascriptEnabled = TRUE)


remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = 4567L, extraCapabilities = eCap)

remDr$open()



remDr$navigate("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/benin-togo-IsfnZDFd/")
match<-remDr$findElement('xpath','//*[@id="col-content"]/h1')
result<-remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="event-status"]/p/strong')
odds<-remDr$findElements('xpath', '//*[@class="name" and contains(text(), "18Bet")]')

odds1 <- data.frame(odds = unlist(sapply(odds, function(x){x$getElementText()})))

pjs$stop()
```

What I want is the 3 odds in last div's but there is a lot of different bookmakers on the page and I can only select all of the bookmaker odds, my goal is to select exact bookmaker's odds but I am not sure how to achieve this since there is no information about the bookmaker in the div's with the odds.

```
<tr class="lo odd">
    <td>
        <div class="l">
            <a class="name2" title="Go to 18bet website!" onclick="return !window.open(this.href)" href="/bookmaker/18bet/link/"><span class="blogos l416"></span></a>&nbsp;
            <a class="name" title="Go to 18bet website!" onclick="return !window.open(this.href)" href="/bookmaker/18bet/link/">18bet</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <span class="ico-bookmarker-info ico-bookmaker-detail">
          <a title="Show more details about 18bet" href="/bookmaker/18bet/"></a>
            </span>
        <span class="ico-bookmarker-info ico-bookmaker-bonus">
          <a onmouseout="globals.getBookmaker(416).cancelBonusOver();" xparam="<div class=&quot;bold&quot;>100% Bonus up to 100€!</div><div>100% first deposit bonus up to 100€! Promocode: WSB100</div>~3" onmouseover="globals.getBookmaker(416).trackBonusOver()" onclick="globals.getBookmaker(416).trackBonusClick();return !window.open(this.href);" href="/bookmaker/18bet/bonus/252"></a>
            </span>
    </td>
    <td class="right odds">
        <div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','2mlnbxv464x0x65lst',416,event,0,1)">2.05</div>
    </td>
    <td class="right odds up">
        <div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','2mlnbxv498x0x0',416,event,0,1)">3.20</div>
    </td>
    <td class="right odds">
        <div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','2mlnbxv464x0x65lsu',416,event,0,1)">3.50</div>
    </td>
    <td class="center info-value"><span>92.1%</span></td>
    <td onmouseout="delayHideTip()" class="check ch3" xparam="The match has already started~2"></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you for the replies in advance.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please have a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Your question is missing some things. First please provide a reproducible example of what you tried before asking, the code you did to try scraping. Then, avoid posting a link to an image, a code sample is more explicit. Then you could use the tags to be more clear, like the language you are using, and why not the `web-scraping` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) examples how you can select `tr` by Bookmakers - **18bet** .

**1**. Find `a` with `class=name` and with `text="18bet"`, get parent `tr` with `class=lo`:

```
 //a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "lo")]
```

**2**. Find `tr` with `class=lo` and child `a` with `class=name` and `text="18bet"`:

```
//tr[contains(@class, "lo") and .//a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]]
```

---

`1` odd: `//a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "lo")]//td[2]`

`X` odd: `//a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "lo")]//td[3]`

`2` odd: `//a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "lo")]//td[4]`

`Payout` odd: `//a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "lo")]//td[5]`

---

Python code example:

```
row = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="name" and .="18bet"]/ancestor::tr[contains(@class, "lo")]')

odd_1 = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[2]')
odd_x = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[3]')
odd_2 = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[4]')
odd_payout = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[5]')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.